# Given the indices of a 2 dimensional list, how can I get the next item over?

Tags: list, python-3.x

Say I have a list of lists:

```
k = [[0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2]]
```

How can I get all the adjacent values? For example:

Given

```
k[1][1]
```

It would return:

```
k[0][1], k[1][0], k[1][2], k[2][1]
```

Comment: By adding and subtracting one, bounded by the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of not writing really repetative code, you could loop over the offsets (which would be in `(-1, 0, 1)`) for both dimensions and verify the locations for each:

```
def adjacent(array,x_orig, y_orig):
    """generates all elements in 2d array around given origin"""
    for x_off in (-1,0,1):
        for y_off in (-1,0,1):
            if x_off == 0 == y_off:
                continue #when they are both 0 it is original space, skip
            x = x_orig + x_off
            y = y_orig + y_off
            if x<0 or y<0:
                continue #don't check negative indices
            try:
                yield array[x][y]
            except IndexError:
                continue #indices were out of bounds
```

This makes it very easy to manipulate if you instead wanted to specify the distance, for example if you instead wanted to get all the locations that were up to 2 indices away you would just change the first few lines:

```
def adjacent(array,x_orig, y_orig, possible_offsets = (-1,0,1)):
    """generates all elements in 2d array around given origin"""
    for x_off in possible_offsets:
        for y_off in possible_offsets:
            ...
```

Then you can just specify `(-2,-1,0,1,2)` and it would give the appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Astar program, here is what I used

```
get_neighbors(array,x,y):
    finalList = []
    x1_Tof, x2_Tof, y1_Tof, y2_Tof = False
    x1 = x + 1
    y1 = y + 1
    x2 = x - 1
    y2 = y - 1
    if x1 >= 0 and x1 <= len(array[0]) and y >= 0 and y <= len(array):
        x1_ToF = True
    #repeat for x2, y1, y2
    if x1_ToF == True:
        finalList.append(array[y][x1])
    #Repeat for x2_ToF...
    return finalList
```

P.S: Remember, in python Y comes first!

Comment: Why does `y` come first in python?  I'd understand if you were doing `row`s and `column`s but why would you do y first?